# onActivityResult() not called when Activity started from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an issue with importing a picture from the Album in Android, because the `onActivityResult()` method is never called.

This is the code that I wrote (called from a fragment not an activity):

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

And by the way, I have defined the `onActivityResult()` but it's never triggered:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult"); // not printed
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: add constructor , super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: I have edited the question, indeed my code has already that line.

Comment: You need to Select image from Gallery right?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Answer (score 112, accepted):

To have `onActivityResult()` called in the fragment, you should call  the fragment's version of `startActivityForResult()`, not the activity's. So in your fragment's code, replace

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

with

```
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: So easy to make that mistake when converting Activities to Fragments :-)

Comment: WOW worked :) nice, we always use getActivity() in fragments :) help me a lot

Comment: this should be the correct answer, the other method of calling a method inside your fragment is a workaround

Comment: I lost some time trying to figure it out. Thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 16):

With this code:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

The onActivityResult must be in the Activity that contains the Fragment. From there you can call any method of the fragment, not in the fragment.

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
myFragment .onCameraResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
```

to do there whatever you want

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see it before! Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this Snippet :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1:
            if(requestCode == 1 && data != null && data.getData() != null){
                Uri _uri = data.getData();

                if (_uri != null) {
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    File photos= new File(imageFilePath);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why u call "super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);" twice ??!