# onActivityResult() not called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have a `MainActivity`, `tabhost` and a `fragment`. I `startActivityForResult` from `fragment`, after completion of task in that activity, I do a `finish` and return the resulting control to the previous fragment. I have explored the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839434/onactivityresult-not-called-when-activity-started-from-fragment). But none of them seem to work for me.

Here is how my `fragment` code:

```
images[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MovieDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("movie", movieObj);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("activity result", "called");
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
                if (data.getBooleanExtra("movieDeleted", true)){
                    TabMovies.refresh();
                }
//                  refresh();
            }
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }
```

Finish `activity`:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("movieDeleted",true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("parent", "called");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I am also giving a `super` call to `onActivityResult()` in `MainActivity`. But none of the methods is getting calling after the `activity` ends..

Comment: did you do super.startActivityForResult()?

Comment: In the `mainactivity`?

Comment: nope in the fragment. You have now done startActivityForResult(intent, 1); can you make super.startActivityForResult(intent, 1); and try again?

Comment: Not calling `super` in `fragment`..

Comment: Calling `super` in fragment now, still not working..

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo please refer to the question again, I have quoted the reference of the post.

Comment: Have you tried it without overriding `onActivityResult` in the Activity?

Comment: Yes, I am `overriding` `onActivityResult` in the `Activity` as well as the `Tab`, just to make sure it is working..

Answer (score -1):

try `getActivity().startActivityForResult()`

Comment: Not working. This is how I am setting my intent for `activity`: `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MovieDetail.class);`

Comment: On updating your answer to account for the OPs info, you might also enhance it to explain *why* your solution works. This will help people finding your answer later.