# in fragment startActivityForResult does not call and it closes it sleft Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know there is so many question related to this but I still not find any solution i have tried all the things.

from [onActivityResult() not called when Activity started from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839434/onactivityresult-not-called-when-activity-started-from-fragment?lq=1) I find

```
      getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

with

```
      startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment?rq=1)

```
     super.onActivityResult //on activity
```

I have also done this but still it's not working.

does any body has solution?

thanks

Comment: have you implement onActivityResult() in Fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);` then you have to call `onActivityResult()` in your activity class where you are adding your fragment.

And If you are using `startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);` inside the fragment then you have to call `onActivityResult()` in your fragment class.

Comment: onActivityResult not being called in Fragment

     super.onActivityResult //on activity

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity you're creating set the result using an intent.  onActivityResult() will catch the intent for you to process.  Here's an example of returning an `int` value.

```
public void sendResultToFragment(int result) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

    resultIntent.putExtra("int-result", result);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
}
```

Keep the `super.onActivityResult(...)` override in your main activity where your fragment lives.

You must override onActivityResult() in your Fragment

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch(requestCode) {
    case PICK_IMAGE:
        int result = data.getInt("int-result");

        // Do stuff

        break;
    default:
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem and i realized that i opened the activity with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

```
new Intent(SplashActivity.this, StartedActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
```

The documentation mentions that when the noHistory attribute is set to true or the flag in the intent, then finish() is called on the Activity when the user navigates away from the Activity.

So just remove and the problem will be solved.

Btw i have the onActivityResult just in the fragment, it works great for me hope it helps.

The answer i found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825254/call-startactivityforresult-from-fragment-doesnt-call-onactivityresult)