# camera intent not returning to fragment not calling on activity result

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I am trying to get to open the camera take an image, store in byte array and then display the image on the fragment.

The camera is opening and taking the picture but when you click the tick it just shows the camera again.

I checked the on activity result and it is not being called. I have all the correct permissions setup.

I have tried the other answers on here but with no success.

Here is how I open the camera in the fragment:

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
private void openCamera(){
    // start main activity
    String [] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), perms)){

        // Start the Camera
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else {
        Log.d("Chex ", "Check did not find permissions starting dialog to explain use of user permissions");
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "This app needs camera permissions to store reciepts", REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE, perms);
    }
}
```

This is my onActivityResult in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Chex ", "On activity results called " + resultCode);

    if (resultCode == AppSettingsDialog.DEFAULT_SETTINGS_REQ_CODE){
        openCamera();
    } else{
        openCamera();
    }

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            transactionImageLocationByteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // Load the image into the imageview
            Glide.with(getActivity()).asBitmap().load(transactionImageLocationByteArray).into(addTransactionCameraButon);

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Capture Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Capture Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
 
Adding on requestPermission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.d("Chex ", "Permission on request result came back with " + grantResults);
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Added onActivityResult to the Main Activity (the host activity for the fragment) but no change:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: plz show onRequestPermissionsResult method in your fragment.

Comment: Ok thanks I will show. That is for Easy permissions

Comment: Just to make sure, you have overridden `onActivityResult` both in the fragment and in the activity and in the activity you have the call to super, but not in the fragment, right?

Comment: Edited it to add

Comment: Oh you have to do it in the activity as well?

Comment: I added this to main activity but it didn't change anything: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: I was not able to picture out the reason why onActivityResult is not called, but please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839434/onactivityresult-not-called-when-activity-started-from-fragment, answer given by jegumi may work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling openCamera method in fragment you need to check this

[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have already gone through this link and nothing seems to be working

Comment: did you try to add into your host Activity ?
     `@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}`

Comment: Did this no change

Comment: you are doing something wrong imo.
Make sure you are calling startActivityForResult method from Fragment's method `this.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: This had no effect either

Answer (score 0):

Remove `super` from `onActivityResult()`.

Remove this line
`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

super will inherit parent class onActivityResult

Comment: Hi, Thanks I did this and it just restarts the main activity

Comment: remove @Override also from `onActivityResult()`

Comment: I did that no change

Comment: Try this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/onactivityresult-nested-fragment-support-library-v23.2/en

Comment: Start like this `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);` and get result in parent activity, and from parent activity call fragment's onActivityResult() .Have a look at this link http://www.codexpedia.com/android/onactivityresult-not-called-in-nested-fragment/

Comment: This starts to help now it is jumping back to the fragment but still not calling on activity result

Comment: Then create a static funtion inside your fragment and call that function from parent activitie's onActivityResult()

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the onActivityResult() :

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == AppSettingsDialog.DEFAULT_SETTINGS_REQ_CODE) {
            // Do something after user returned from app settings screen
            openCamera();
        } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                transactionImageLocationByteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                // Load the image into the imageview
                Glide.with(getActivity()).asBitmap().load(transactionImageLocationByteArray).into(addTransactionCameraButon);

            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Capture Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Capture Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**edit :** Add the below code to your Activity's `onActivityResult()` method.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentId);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks can you explain more I am wondering what changes you mean. I can see you add it to the if else but how is this different to having a second if statement? Or is there something I am missing thanks. On activity is not being called at all see how I have the log statement before anything in on activity result that is to test if it is being called

Comment: first of all you checking result code instead checking request code in resultCode == AppSettingsDialog.DEFAULT_SETTINGS_REQ_CODE, so need to change this

Comment: see i have edited my answer. for that case you need to find fragment and need to call fragment's onActivityResult() method